# How to call a REST API with Java Spark Framework?

Tags: java, rest, firebase-authentication, spark-java

I'm referring to the Spark micro framework here(not apache spark). I need to call a REST API, for instance, a google API, in an application written in Java Spark.

I don't see a direct way to do it in their documentation. I saw a library called Okhttp for java. Not sure if that helps.

Could someone please guide? Couldn't find anything useful on Google. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

actually there are no problems using OkHttp
but take a look at this article if you are using java 9+, it has a built in http client
https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.